# Bootstrap dropdown not working in meteor

Tags: meteor

I am manually including the bootstrap 3.1.1 files in my meteor project and styling is fine. When I put the code below in bootply it works but when using in my meteor app, I see the 'dropdown trigger' link but but clicking it does nothing?

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider" role="presentation"></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" href="#">Separated link</a></li>  
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you adding the Bootstrap JS? I would recommend using the `bootstrap-3` package on Atmosphere -https://github.com/mangasocial/meteor-bootstrap-3 - It uses Bootstrap 3.1.0 but should be easy to update, and I'm sure the author would accept a pull request.

Comment: I have a bootstrap folder containing bootstrap js, font, css files. I want to do it like this because I plan to add some custom styles later.  Bootstrap styling seems to be working fine with this setup...

Comment: What you can do is add the bootstrap as a package to your `packages/` folder. Just copy the structure of the `bootstrap-3` package. You can customize the files in the package as much as you want this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

argh!! I see now that I had both `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` files, removing `bootstrap.js` solved my problem.  Sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Iron Router try to delete href attribute from dropdown trigger:

```
<a data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown trigger</a>
```

And add cursor pointer to a tag in your CSS:

```
a { cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: I tries this and still the dropdown does nothing