# Bootstrap drowpdown not working in Meteor

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

folks.  I'm working on a Meteor application and I have the following section in my navigation template meant to render a dynamically built dropdown menu.

For some reason, it's not dropping down, and I have no idea why.

I'm using the `twbs:boostrap` package to provide Bootstrap.

**Template Section**:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Browse <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            {{#each categories}}
                <li><a href="{{pathFor 'browse' slug=this.slug}}">{{name}}</a></li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Categories helper**:

```
Template.registerHelper('categories', function() {
    return Categories.find();
});
```

When I inspect the DOM on the page, the menu is there, and I followed the documentation on Bootstrap's website to make sure I have everything right, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.   Paths are being generated correctly also from Iron Router (`pathFor`).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know about Meteor, but did you add the [dropdown plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) for bootstrap? Did the console show any message?

Comment: No console messages or anything, it just doesn't drop down.  Nothing happens at all.

Comment: Check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21954365/bootstrap-dropdown-not-working-in-meteor. I'm not sure if it will be helpful at all, but you might try. It's really difficult to see what's going on without seeing some example. Did you add the javascript plugins? I've never used Meteor so I don't know if the libraries are colliding between themselves. Verify if you added the javascript files (both bootstrap javascript file and the dropdown plugin itself)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that something must be wrong with the twbs:bootstrap package, because if I use a version of Bootstrap from CDN, it seems to work fine.

Thanks to Eric for his assistance and response, it definitely helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Browse <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="{{pathFor 'browse'}} ">test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{pathFor 'browse'}} ">test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{pathFor 'browse'}} ">test</a></li>
                    {{#each categories}}
                            <li><a href="{{pathFor 'browse' slug=this.slug}}">{{name}}</a></li>
                        {{/each}}
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Does your foreach work correctly? try with static list like in the code above to see what happens.